# How to fix rake db:migrate error after migrating to AWS Cloud9 from c9.io?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, cloud9, aws-cloud9

I just migrated my old Rails project from c9.io to AWS Cloud9, after migration, I ran

`bundle install`

and it works fine, but then when I tried to run:

`rake db:migrate`

this error happened:

> /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in
>   `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
>   /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in`
>   block (2 levels) in '
>   /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in
>   `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
>   /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in`
>   block (2 levels) in '
>   /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in
>   `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
>   /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in`
>   block (2 levels) in '
>   /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in
>   `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
>   /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in`
>   block (2 levels) in '
>   /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in
>   `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
>   /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in`
>   block (2 levels) in '
>   /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in
>   `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
>   /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in`
>   block (2 levels) in '
>   /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in
>   `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
>   /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in`
>   block (2 levels) in '
>   /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in
>   `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
>   /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in`
>   block (2 levels) in '
>   /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in
>   `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
>   /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in`
>   block (2 levels) in '
>   /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in
>   `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
>   /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in`
>   block (2 levels) in '
>   /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in
>   `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
>   /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in`
>   block (2 levels) in '
>   /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in
>   `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
>   /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in`
>   block (2 levels) in '
>   /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in
>   `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
>   /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in`
>   block (2 levels) in '
>   /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in
>   `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
>   /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in`
>   block (2 levels) in '
>   /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in
>   `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
>   /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in`
>   block (2 levels) in '
>   /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in
>   `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
>   /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in`
>   block (2 levels) in '
>   /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in
>   `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
>   /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in`
>   block (2 levels) in '
>   /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in
>   `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
>   /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in`
>   block (2 levels) in '
>   /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in
>   `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
>   /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in`
>   block (2 levels) in '
>   /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in
>   `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
>   /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in`
>   block (2 levels) in '
>   /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in
>   `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
>   /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in`
>   block (2 levels) in '
>   /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in
>   `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
>   /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in`
>   block (2 levels) in '
>   /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in
>   `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
>   /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:138:in`
>   local_cache_key'
>   /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:74:in
>   `middleware'
>   /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/application/bootstrap.rb:79:in`
>   block in '
>   /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in
>   `instance_exec'
>   /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in`
>   run'
>   /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in
>   `block in run_initializers'
>   /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in`
>   run_initializers'
>   /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in
>   `initialize!' /home/ec2-user/environment/config/environment.rb:5:in`
>   '
>   /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
>   /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in`block in require'
>   /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
>   /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in`require'
>   /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/application.rb:328:in
>   `require_environment!'
>   /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/application.rb:457:in`
>   block in run_tasks_blocks' Tasks: TOP => db:migrate => environment
>   (See full trace by running task with --trace)

Does anyone know how to resolve this?

Comment: which `ruby` version you're using in the project?

Comment: @UdAY ruby 2.6.0p0 (2018-12-25 revision 66547) [x86_64-linux]

Comment: @qhtn Check your database.yml did you give any tab there or any whitespace?

Comment: @Vishal I dont think so

Comment: Have you tried `bundle exec rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production`?

Comment: I just did, and the terminal gave me the same error